# Angular 2: Http asynchronous call

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am using Http Service from Angular2 :

**My login component:**

```
    doLogin() {
        this.authenticationService.inValidateSession();    
 this.authenticationService.userConfiguration=this.httpService.login(this.user.email,this.user.password)
        this.router.navigate(['/site']);

    }
```

- Once user submits credentials , dologin with invalidate the old session if any.
- Will do the server login
- And will save the user configuration it will get from the server like name and groups...
  _ And will redirect to default homepage.

**HttpService**

```
login(username:string,password:string) {
     let headers = new Headers();
     this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers,username,password);
     this.http.get(this.url,{headers:headers}).subscribe(this.extractData,this.handleError);
     return this.configFromLogin;  
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  if(res.status==200){
    let body = res.json();
    var result={"config":body,
                "x-xsrf-token":res.headers.get('x-xsrf-token')};
    this.configFromLogin=result;
  }
  else{
    //console.log(error);
    // throw exception or use this.error() method
  }
}
```

Since **Server provides Token** authentication which we need to use for all the Post Requests, i save it in Session.

**My Problems or Doubts:**

1. When i debug **doLogin()** codes get **executed first**
   (saveInSession) even **before HttpService extractData** is executed.
   Why ? i know Http get is async call but how can i make doLogin wait
   ?
2. In HttpService i am checking if response is 200 then i am saving it
   otherwise i want to throw error and use the HandleError method ,
   which i am using in subscribe method of Observable. Is it possible ?

Please help me with above two problems, in case of questions i am available to answer.

Thanks

Comment: what is `this.configFromLogin` in `HttpService`?

Comment: @Supamiu : this is just result from server , which i am sending back. var result={"config":body,
                "x-xsrf-token":res.headers.get('x-xsrf-token')};   I will store it in session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle the return value of async function in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413433/how-to-handle-the-return-value-of-async-function-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you don't wait for the http request to be complete before calling `router.navigate`.

Your service should return an observable in order to tell the calling component that the request is finished and everything is good to navigate.

**login component**

```
    doLogin() {
        this.authenticationService.inValidateSession();    
        this.httpService.login(this.user.email,this.user.password).subscribe(result => {
            this.authenticationService.userConfiguration=result;
            this.router.navigate(['/site']);
        }, 
        error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

**HttpService**

```
login(username:string,password:string):Observable<any> {
     let headers = new Headers();
     this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers,username,password);

     //We will return the http observable, mapped with our auth function
     return this.http.get(this.url,{headers:headers}) 
     .map(this.extractData);//We bind the authentication process on the observable
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    if(res.status !== 200){
        throw new Error('Not a 200, bla bla details');
    }
    let body = res.json();
    var result={"config":body,
                "x-xsrf-token":res.headers.get('x-xsrf-token')};
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT**: I added a `throw` in the `extractData` method, it allows you to throw an error which will be catched by `rxjs` and handled in the `onError` parameter of `subscribe`.