# How to handle the return value of async function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-services

The casesService function handles a HTTP req and response and returns a single object. I want to return the object. But since it is an async functionality it returns empty object(this.caseBook). I want it to return the object only after it has value.

```
public initData (selectedCaseId: number): CaseBook {   

       this.casesService
        .GetCaseById(selectedCaseId)
        .subscribe(data => {

            this.caseBook = data;

        });
       return this.caseBook; 
 }
```

Comment: but callbacks are not working !

Comment: You cannot return data directly from an asynchronous method. Use promises or callbacks. What do you mean it is not working?

Comment: callback didn't properly return the value !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For typescript Promise, you can make it work this way:

```js
public async initData (selectedCaseId: number): CaseBook {       
    return await this.casesService.GetCaseById(selectedCaseId);
}
```

but since your `this.casesService.GetCaseById` is an Observable, you may not possible to return pure value from it directly. return an Observable instead.

```js
public initData (selectedCaseId: number): Observable<CaseBook> {   
   return this.casesService
    .GetCaseById(selectedCaseId);
}
```

and then you can bind it for angular2 with `async` pipe:

```js
{{this.initData() | async}}
```

for better performance, suggest to bind a value for it, for example:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initData().subscribe( data => this.caseBook = data );
}
```

Comment: i get an error stating that :
Type 'typeof CaseBook' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.