# Cannot assess the http post response data from outside of the .subscribe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using a http request to get a url from a server and it returns correct data as the response. after i set the data to a variable i cannot access the variable data from other method.

this is my code

```
public  urlcheck:any;

constructor(public http: Http) {

   //what i want to do is something like this, it works when i do like this.
   //urlcheck = "http://10.0.2.2/mysite/";


   this.urlcheck = this.http.get('http://localhost/website/index.php/Admin/getpublicip');
   this.urlcheck.subscribe(data => {
      //console output is  ('my data: http://10.0.2.2/mysite')
      console.log('my data: ', data["_body"]);
      this.urlcheck = data["_body"];

   })
//console output is ("check url[object Object]")
console.log("check url"+this.urlcheck);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please format your output properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle the return value of async function in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413433/how-to-handle-the-return-value-of-async-function-in-typescript)

Comment: BTW, don't use `Http`, it's ancient, use `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two things I think. Your getUrl returns a promise, not a string so you should be able to do this.

```
this.getUrl().then((url: string) => { this.baseurl = url; }
```

Or.. you could set the baseurl from your http request since you subscribe to the result, so no actual need to return a promise.

```
subscribe((data: any) => { this.baseurl = data.data; }
```

Code example:

```
    geturl(){
     return new Promise(resolve => {
         this.http.get('http://localhost/mechmarcl_website/index.php/Admin/getpublicip')
             .map(res => res.json())
             .subscribe((data: any) => {

                 // you receive the data here, so you can use the data here
                 // For example:
                 this.baseurl = data.data;

                 // what you tried to do here I think with this line?
                 this.url= JSON.stringify(data.data);

                 resolve ((data.data));
             }, error => {
             resolve(error);
             });
     });
   }
```

Or the promise way.

```
constructor(public http: Http) {
     this.geturl().then((url: string) => {
        this.baseurl = url;
     }, (err: any) => {
       // handle your promise rejection here
     }
    });
   }
```

Comment: Can you show me a example, because im new to this. thanks.

Comment: Why do you need an example? The answer already described the whole. Still you can get example from here: https://vitalflux.com/angular-promise-explained-code-example/

Comment: @ThilinaRathnayake I've added an "example" using both ways using your code provided above.

Comment: @Bert Maurau i have tried both. but the console console output of the variable is "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `then()` for resolving the promise:

`this.geturl().then(url => this.baseurl = url);`

Comment: i have tried this. but it didnt work.is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @ThilinaRathnayake, as the promise call is asynchronous, it is expected to see `undefined` in console.log right after the call. You may use `async` / `await` statements for your purposes.

Comment: where should i use async / wait

Comment: I think it would be good to get in that concept in general:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Otherwise you may add a method like this in your service:

```
    async initUrl () {
        await this.geturl().then(url => this.baseurl = url);
    }
```
And call this function in the constructor as the constructor itself cannot be async:

```
constructor() {
  this.initUrl();
  console.log(this.baseurl);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:
`this.geturl().then(url => this.baseurl = url.toString());`

Or you can go with:

```
let baseurl = await this.geturl();
this.baseurl = baseurl.toString();
```

But I think the first one will do the work.
@Anton Mitsev code looks promising too.